# Python Selenium: How to select dropdown menu

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

[image]I need to select the item - "Property owner statement" in dropdown menu. In the screenshot, it shows there has no unique name I can select on the ul class so the code doesn't works.

```
[![from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = 'https://system.arthuronline.co.uk/genieliew1/dashboards/index'
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

titleTags=driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "select2-result")
select.selectByVisibleText("Property Owner Statement")][1]][1]
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to share the URL.

Comment: That dropdown is not 'Select' type, it is a 'div' tag, so you can't use Select. The URL you posted needs credentials to login, can you post the credentials?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    titleTags = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "select2-result")

    # select the title dropdown
    select_titleTags = Select(titleTags)
    select.selectByVisibleText("Property Owner Statement")][1]][1]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The drop-down is not a select type class. You can't use selenium select class.

You need to click on the dropdown element first and then click on specific element listed. Use `WebDriverWait()` and wait for element to be clickable.

```
url = 'https://system.arthuronline.co.uk/genieliew1/dashboards/index'
driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@id='select2-drop']"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[contains(.,'Property Owner Statement')]"))).click()
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried this way but it can only complete to click the drop down menu. I think the reason is when the cursor point to the text and then the text will be highlighted. The class name will change as well.

Comment: What error are you getting with that code?

Comment: Hi, plese see the error from the post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74966220/python-selenium-how-to-select-the-drop-down-menu-with-highlighted-feature?noredirect=1#comment132293875_74966220

Comment: If I select the id = select2-drop then it basiclly not working. Therefore, I search the element on Chrome and select the container s2id__statement and then selenium can click the drop down menu but that container has no id called Property Owner Statement