# Python Selenium: How to select the drop down menu with highlighted feature

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to select the drop down menu. Selenium can control Chrome to click the drop down list and the list shows the options. However, it fails to select and click the options. Is it because the drop down list has a feature when the cursor point to the text and the text will be highlighted. The class name will be changed.

Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=options)

url = 'https://system.arthuronline.co.uk/genieliew1/dashboards/index'
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'username'))).send_keys("")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'password'))).send_keys("")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[type='submit']"))).click()

url = 'https://system.arthuronline.co.uk/genieliew1/units/view/377225/filter:Transaction-_statement:property-owner;Transaction-_payeeEntityId:149280;Transaction-unit_id:377225;Transaction-_order:default;/page:1#tab-transactions-7322b9'
driver.get(url)

#Click the drop down menu
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@id='s2id__statement']"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[contains(.,'Property Owner Statement')]"))).click()
```

This is the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ElementClickInterceptedException          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-3afc38e2a733> in <module>
     25 #Click the drop down menu
     26 WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@id='s2id__statement']"))).click()
---> 27 WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[contains(.,'Property Owner Statement')]"))).click()

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py in click(self)
     91     def click(self) -> None:
     92         """Clicks the element."""
---> 93         self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
     94 
     95     def submit(self):

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py in _execute(self, command, params)
    408             params = {}
    409         params["id"] = self._id
--> 410         return self._parent.execute(command, params)
    411 
    412     def find_element(self, by=By.ID, value=None) -> WebElement:

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    442         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    443         if response:
--> 444             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    445             response["value"] = self._unwrap_value(response.get("value", None))
    446             return response

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    247                 alert_text = value["alert"].get("text")
    248             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)  # type: ignore[call-arg]  # mypy is not smart enough here
--> 249         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <div id="outer">...</div> is not clickable at point (1280, 646). Other element would receive the click: <div id="select2-drop-mask" class="select2-drop-mask" style="width: 2560px; height: 1293px;"></div>
  (Session info: chrome=108.0.5359.124)
Stacktrace:
0   chromedriver                        0x00000001055fff38 chromedriver + 4910904
1   chromedriver                        0x000000010557fa03 chromedriver + 4385283
2   chromedriver                        0x00000001051c4747 chromedriver + 472903
3   chromedriver                        0x0000000105212588 chromedriver + 791944
4   chromedriver                        0x000000010520f9ec chromedriver + 780780
5   chromedriver                        0x000000010520c671 chromedriver + 767601
6   chromedriver                        0x000000010520b18b chromedriver + 762251
7   chromedriver                        0x00000001051fbac3 chromedriver + 699075
8   chromedriver                        0x000000010522f112 chromedriver + 909586
9   chromedriver                        0x00000001051fb0ed chromedriver + 696557
10  chromedriver                        0x000000010522f2ce chromedriver + 910030
11  chromedriver                        0x000000010524a28e chromedriver + 1020558
12  chromedriver                        0x000000010522eee3 chromedriver + 909027
13  chromedriver                        0x00000001051f930c chromedriver + 688908
14  chromedriver                        0x00000001051fa88e chromedriver + 694414
15  chromedriver                        0x00000001055cd1de chromedriver + 4702686
16  chromedriver                        0x00000001055d1b19 chromedriver + 4721433
17  chromedriver                        0x00000001055d928e chromedriver + 4752014
18  chromedriver                        0x00000001055d291a chromedriver + 4725018
19  chromedriver                        0x00000001055a6b02 chromedriver + 4545282
20  chromedriver                        0x00000001055f1888 chromedriver + 4851848
21  chromedriver                        0x00000001055f1a05 chromedriver + 4852229
22  chromedriver                        0x0000000105607e5f chromedriver + 4943455
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6bdeb109 _pthread_start + 148
24  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6bde6b8b thread_start + 15[!
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTFKk.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTFKk.jpg)

Comment: The webpage is asking for user credentials to login.

Comment: can you share the html of the site? because we cannot login